# Enum internal map initialization in a Spring context

Tags: java, spring, enums

Considering the following enum :

```
public enum EnumBrand {
    visa("VISA", EnumCardType.visa),
    mastercard("MASTERCARD", EnumCardType.mastercard),
    amex("AMERICAN EXPRESS", EnumCardType.amex),
    maestro("MAESTRO", EnumCardType.mastercard),
    unknown("UNKNOWN", EnumCardType.visa);

    private String name;
    private EnumCardType cardType;

    EnumBrand(String name, EnumCardType cardType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cardType = cardType;
    }

    private static final Map<String, EnumBrand> h = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (EnumBrand enumBrand : EnumBrand.values()) {
            h.put(enumBrand.getName(), enumBrand);
        }
    }

    public static EnumBrand fromName(String name) {
        try {
            EnumBrand type = h.get(name);
            if (type == null)
                return EnumBrand.unknown;
            return type;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return EnumBrand.unknown;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public EnumCardType getCardType() {
        return cardType;
    }
}
```

The following code workds in a unit test context.

When used in Spring context, getCardType always return a null.

```
EnumBrand enumBrand = EnumBrand.fromName("VISA");
EnumCardType enumCardType = enumBrand.getCardType();
```

I'm guessing that the static init is involved, but I'd like to understand why exactly this doesn't work with Spring

Comment: It's not about exact your issue, but why do you need map `h` when you can use `values()` method? For performance?

Comment: because its more convenient than looping on values() each time you create an enum instance, don't you think ?